# Проблема с PWM вентилятором Arduino

Tags: arduino

Я подключаю PWM вентилятор к ардуино (Все как надо GND к GND, 12v к 12v, PWM к A0, tahometer к A1) Генерирую шим сигнал, но тут проблема. Вентилятор включается только на 137 и дальше вентилятор не ускорятеся, выключается тоже только на 137, в чем проблема?

Comment: скорее всего вам не хватает мощности.

Comment: @Monomax простите, мощности чего? Аккумулятора?

Comment: **Аккумулятора** -возможно, какова у него токовая отдача и на какую характеристику рассчитан двигатель вентилятора?

Comment: Да действительно проблема именно в этом, спасибо!

Comment: @Log1c0 оформил как ответ, отметьте как решенный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы подключаете к аналоговому выходу. Вам нужно подключать к цифровому выходу, который поддерживает PWM (поддерживают не все выходы, смотрите документацию ардуины)